# php how to redirect to last visited page when logged out from session

Tags: php, authentication, session, redirect

I have a couple of pages protected with a login; `add.php`, `settings.php` and `archive.php`
At the top of each of these pages i have this code:

```
// check login
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['blog_login'])){
    $_SESSION['last_visited'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}
```

When logging out, the page request goes to `logout.php`. Logout.php looks like below:

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['blog_login']);
header("Location: login.php");
```

When logging in again, i want to go to the page i was before. This is my `login.php`

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $error = NULL;
    if(isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'])){
        $user = array(
                        "username" => $admin_name,
                        "password"=> $admin_passw           
                );
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        if($username == $user['username'] && $pass == $user['password']){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['blog_login'] = $username;
            header('Location:'.$_SESSION['last_visited']);                      
        }
        else {
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Incorrect login data</div>';

        }

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the `header('Location:'.$_SESSION['last_visited']);` line does not send me to the previous page i was before logging out. 
What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: You can add to mysql user table a value, so update user `DB` before logout with `$_SESSION['last_visited']`, so when he login you can set from db last page on redirect and if is empty go to default page.

Comment: Well, i am not using a database!

Comment: _“Unfortunately, the `header('Location:'.$_SESSION['last_visited']);` line does not send me to the previous page i was before logging out.”_ - so what happens instead then? No redirect anywhere at all? Errors? Redirect, but to a different URL then you expected to? Have you checked what `$_SESSION['last_visited']` actually contains at this point at least?

Comment: You are right CBroe, `echo $_SESSION['last_visited'];` outputs nothing at all! Strange...

Comment: You're not saving your session. In your lougout script add `session_write_close()` before redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` for this.

Skip the line`$_SESSION['last_visited'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` in `add.php`, `settings.php` and `archive.php`

In your `logout.php` add the line `$_SESSION['last_visited'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`

So logout.php:

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['blog_login']);
$_SESSION['last_visited'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; //bind the last visited page you came from to a session
header("Location: login.php");
```

(Don't need to change `login.php`)

Answer (score 0):

you can store your current page URL in a variable after logout redirects to your URL address.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be one of the following two reasons.

1. You did not start session on your login.php page, it must start with:
   session_start();
2. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] does not output anything.

Answer (score -1):

Use $_COOKIE and set a cookie for last_visited_page then after user logs in check if cookie exist and if cookie exist then redirect to last_visited page using cookie.

You should not use $_SESSION for this because you log someone out then you clear $_SESSION data using session_destroy(); and when user revisits your website a new session is started. But if you use cookie then you don't have to worry about that. Because cookie will be saved in browser so if he logins from same browser you can use $_COOKIE['last_visited_page'] and send him to his last visited page.

Comment: The session does not get destroyed in the code that was shown, only `$_SESSION['blog_login']` gets unset here, to mark the user as not logged in any more.

Comment: I know in that code it doesn't get destroyed but if you look at it for real work application it should destroy session to logout user. You should not promote his approach for logging user out.